# SQL Pivot return all rows on table join even if no record exists (cross join?)

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, pivot

I have managed to successfully pivot my data against months. However the pivot only returns rows that have a value in my KPIData table.

I am pivoting Months against KPIData and bringing in some fields from KPIGraph for filtering. I would like to be able to show nulls in the row for each month column whenever I add a KPIGraphs row and there is no related record in KPIData. At present this only works if I add atleast 1 value in my KPIData table which ofcourse then links everything up together due to the joins.

The relationship is set as follows:
http://goo.gl/9lvhF

I have done some reading up and found that I will need to likey use a cross join here? I have never used one of these and after some further digging it has completely confused me in its implementation into my pivot sql.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[GraphID], CASE MonthID
            WHEN 1 THEN 'October'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'November'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'December'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'January'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'February'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'March'
            WHEN 7 THEN 'April'
            WHEN 8 THEN 'May'
            WHEN 9 THEN 'June'
            WHEN 10 THEN 'July'
            WHEN 11 THEN 'August'
            WHEN 12 THEN 'September'
            END AS [Month], [t0].[Value], [t3].[Graph_Type], [t5].[Department], [t6].
        [Type], [t8].[Financial_Year], [t7].[FYID], [t4].[KPITypeID]
    FROM [KPIDatas] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [Months] AS [t1] ON [t1].[ID] = [t0].[MonthID]
    INNER JOIN [KPIGraphs] AS [t2] ON [t2].[ID] = [t0].[GraphID]
    INNER JOIN [GraphTypes] AS [t3] ON [t3].[ID] = [t2].[GraphTypeID]
    INNER JOIN [KPIs] AS [t4] ON [t4].[ID] = [t2].[KPIID]
    INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t5] ON [t5].[ID] = [t4].[DeptID]
    INNER JOIN [KPITypes] AS [t6] ON [t6].[ID] = [t4].[KPITypeID]
    INNER JOIN [CSFs] AS [t7] ON [t7].[ID] = [t4].[CSFID]
    INNER JOIN [FYs] AS [t8] ON [t8].[ID] = [t7].[FYID]
    ) TableDate
PIVOT(SUM(Value) FOR [Month] IN (
            [October], [November], [December], [January], [February], [March], [April]
            , [May], [June], [July], [August], [September]
            )) PivotTable
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: any chance you could create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data?  The only thing I can think of without seeing any data is to use CTE or a calendar table to create a list of months to join on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this just after more messing around. My sub query needed a RIGHT OUTER JOIN to ensure it pulled back a Null. These are then expanded out across my months when the Pivot code comes in to play.

```
                      dbo.KPIDatas AS t0 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
```